# How to change options of a selection because of another selection with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to change the options of a selection dynamically in HTML if a checkbox is checked/because of another selection.

These are my selections:

```html
<!-- choosing -->
<select name="choose" id="choose">
  <option value="">-- choose --</option>
  <option value="o1">Option1</option>
  <option value="o2">Option2</option>
</select>

<!-- if choose == o1 -->
<select name="subject1" id="subject1">
  <option value="">-- choose --</option>
  <option value="Religion">Religion</option>
  <option value="Spansich">Spanisch</option>
  <option value="Französisch">Französisch</option>
  <option value="Englisch">Englisch</option>
  <option value="Latein">Latein</option>
</select>

<!-- if choose == o2 -->
<select name="subject2" id="subject2">
  <option value="">-- choose --</option>
  <option value="Geschichte">Geschichte</option>
  <option value="GMK">GMK</option>
  <option value="WBS">WBS</option>
  <option value="Kunst">Kunst</option>
</select>
```

I guess you would use JavaScript for this, but I'm really new to all of that, so, could you show me what kind of function could be used to solve this.

Comment: add your code, what you have tried to achieve

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: if we solve u this problem  Google will remain advanced for you. just go on step by step. as ur help i am giving u the step

1.  create an addEventListner when u click the checkbox
2. on that u check if checkbox is check or not and  do some operation

Thats is so simple

if you stuck then `stackoverflow` always here

Comment: If forgot to add code before. Now I added it.

Comment: @sayalok please give me a more detailed answer

Comment: @1337HaxX0r  If select list  "subject1" and "subject2" options are always same as above then show or hide accordingly using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="choose" id="choose">
  <option value="">-- choose --</option>
  <option value="o1">Option1</option>
  <option value="o2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select name="subject" id="subject"></select>

<script>
    const option = document.getElementById("choose")

    option.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {

        let options1 =  `<option value="">-- choose --</option>
                          <option value="Religion">Religion</option>
                          <option value="Spansich">Spanisch</option>
                          <option value="Französisch">Französisch</option>
                          <option value="Englisch">Englisch</option>
                          <option value="Latein">Latein</option>`

        let options2 =  `<option value="">-- choose --</option>
                     <option value="Geschichte">Geschichte</option>
                     <option value="GMK">GMK</option>
                     <option value="WBS">WBS</option>
                     <option value="Kunst">Kunst</option>`

        if(option.value == "o1")
            document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = options1;
        else if(option.value == "o2")
            document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = options2;
        else
            document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = '';
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Something is wrong with that: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select name="choose" id="choose" onchange="custom_change()">
  <option value="">-- choose --</option>
  <option value="o1">Option1</option>
  <option value="o2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select name="subject2" id="subject"></select>
<script>

function custom_change()
{
    var choose_value = document.getElementById("choose").value;
    var option_1 = "<option value=''>-- choose --</option><option value='Religion'>Religion</option><option value='GMK'>GMK</option><option value='WBS'>WBS</option><option value='Kunst'>Kunst</option>";
    var option_2 = "<option value=''>-- choose --</option><option value='Geschichte'>Geschichte</option><option value='GMK'>GMK</option><option value='WBS'>WBS</option><option value='Kunst'>Kunst</option>";  

        if(choose_value == "o1")
            document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = option_1;
        else if(choose_value == "o2")
            document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = option_2;
        else
            document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = '';

}
</script>
```